# "As a rule of thumb, make all your methods virtual" in C++ - sound advice?

Tags: c++, virtual

I just happened upon the statement in the title. The full quote is:

> As a rule of thumb, make all your methods virtual (including the
>   destructor, but not constructors) to avoid problems associated with
>   omission of the virtual keyword.

I found this in the Wrox book *Professional C++*. [You can google it to check.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22As+a+rule+of+thumb%2C+make+all+your+methods+virtual%22)

Is there anything to it? I would have thought that you'd only provide select extension points, not by-default extensibility. For instance, [a 2001 article by Herb Sutter says so](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). Has anything changed dramatically since then to make the opposite the ruling norm? (Note that I'm a C++ noob so I haven't been following the discussion for the last decade.)

Comment: I've heard this a few times but nobody's ever been able to convince me to follow it. Seems a bit flimsy to me. I tend to agree with your analysis. Of course it's only ever going to be highly subjective.

Comment: Doesn't the inclusion of the first virtual function in a class complicate the internal representation, by forcing a vtable or something like that?  I would have thought it's 'Only go virtual when you really have to'.

Comment: ... unless you are designing a game.

Comment: @Marlon: plenty of games are written with Lua, Objective-C, Java, etc., where dynamic calls are the norm. If you're making Modern Warfare 4, sure, it's a performance concern, but hopefully those guys already know the tradeoffs.

Comment: I like this question and I was genuinely interested in a C++ expert's input. I don't see how this question is not constructive. Maybe offtopic for SO but there's so many StackExchange sites now I wouldn't know where to put it.

Comment: @dreamlax: It's "not constructive" because it "will likely solicit opinion, debate ..."

Comment: Okay, that was my first C++ question, and it took you ten minutes to close it ... :) Frankly, I can't see the rationale behind this funny SO policy of closing questions as "non constructive" which "will likely solicit opinion and debate" because **the most useful questions for learners to learn are precisely those questions eliciting opinion, debate and insightful comments by the experts**. Leaving zillions of repetitive "how do I do X in PHP and jQuery?" alive and closing debates that get behind the superficial *howto* aspect **doesn't make any sense to me**. But well, what can yo do?

Comment: It is a dumb advise and I suggest to burn the book in question for the greater good. When there's no reason to do something, then you shouldn't do it. You can run into problems by following the "advise" as well.

Comment: Herb Sutter's advice is more advanced; being more advanced, you'll find it used in fewer places.

Comment: At least in my opinion, this is a question that can be answered constructively. Yes, the ultimate conclusion is going to be mostly a matter of opinion, but the considerations that would lead to the conclusion are mostly objective, and the conclusion is just a matter of deciding which of those matters the most (in your current situation).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there anything to it?

The advice is **BAD**, there is no question about it. Reading something like that would be enough to stay away from the book and its author.

You see, virtual keyword indicates "you can or should override this method - it was designed for this".

For any non-trivial task, I cannot imagine a reasonable system of classes that would allow user (i.e. other programmer) to override every single single method in every derived class. It is normal to have base abstract class with only virtual methods. However, once you start making derived classes, there's no reason for slapping "virtual" onto everything - some methods don't need to be extensible.

Making everything virtual means that at any point of code, no matter which method is called, you can never be sure that the class will do what you want, because somebody could have overriden your method, breaking it in the process (According to Murphy's Law it will happen). This will make your code unreliable, and hard to maintain. Another very interesting thing is the way virtual methods are called in constructors. Basically, by following this advice you sacrifice code readability/reliability in exchange for not doing a quite uncommon typo. In *my* opinion, it is not worth it.

In comparison, non-virtual method guarantees that no matter what happens, at this point of code, the code will always work as you expect (not counting the bugs you haven't discovered yet). I.e. somebody else won't replace your method with broken alternative.

The advice reminds me a common error some newbie programmers tend to do: instead of developing simple solution that will fix the problem, they get distracted and attempt to make code universal and extensible. As a result, project takes longer to finish or never becomes complete - because universal solution for every possible scenario takes more effort/development time than a localized solution limited only to current problem at hand.

Instead of following this "virtual" advice, I'd recommend to stick with [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) and [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). They worked well for *me*. However, they are not guaranteed to work well for everybody else.

Comment: Thanks, @SigTerm. Let me say that I've found the book in question - 2011 edition, updated for C++11 - to be otherwise a very useful introduction to the language. I'm reading slowly, and various sources in parallel to make things really clear for me, and I was already primed against by-default extensibility as in Java. So this advice surprised me. - You're saying: "Another very interesting thing is the way virtual methods are called in constructors." [Googled this](http://www.google.com?q=virtual+method+in+constructor); sounds like you should rather avoid calling virtual methods in ctors.

Answer (score 12):

I don't agree with the principle.

In the past, some were concerned about overuse of `virtual` due to performance concerns. This is still somewhat valid, but not overly problematic on today's hardware. (Keep in mind, most other languages incur similar penalties these days. For instance, the 400MHz iPhone 2G used Objective C which incurs a virtual method call on every function call.)

I think you should only use `virtual` on methods where it seems useful and reasonable to want to override it in a subclass. To me, it serves as a hint to other programmers (or your future self) as "this is a place where subclasses can sensibly customize behavior." If replacing the method in a subclass would be confusing or weird to implement, don't use `virtual`.

Also, for simple setters and getters, it's probably a bad idea as it will inhibit inlining.

Answer (score 3):

There will be a tiny loss in performance and a few bytes of memory wasted.

The real problem is that it makes the code less maintainable because you are saying something about the function that isn't true.  It could cause a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It can't hurt. If you don't have a subclass which redefines the function, nothing is different. I can see this technique being useful if you have a lot of inheritance going on and you might lose track of what classes inherit which.

Personally, I don't make every class method virtual...but that's just me. Having everything `virtual` seems to make things look more confusing, imho.

Comment: It can hurt.  Having >0 virtual functions increases the object size.  It can potentially obscure the author's intent.  It can potentially prevent the compiler from inlining.

Comment: The other language I use frequently (Python) makes every function virtual by default (there is no keyword.) So using this approach can't be all that bad.

Comment: I see what you mean @OliCharlesworth ... I was just saying that the code would still work correctly. But agreed...it's not the most efficient approach.

Comment: It can hurt. Override wrong method, and you'll break all inherited functionality, which can result in non-trivial bugs. Non-virtual method prevents this from happening. And frankly, python is a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a good rule of thumb for beginners with C++. It's not really harmful except in very specific scenarios (ones faced by programmers who know exactly what the tradeoffs of the virtual keyword are), and is one less thing to think about.

However, like every rule of thumb, it's oversimplifying the situation, and when one grows to think about how to communicate to other programmers what methods may or may not be good candidates for redefining, one has outgrown the rule of thumb.