# Why does C++ not let baseclasses implement a derived class' inherited interface?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface

Here is what I am talking about

```
// some guy wrote this, used as a Policy with templates
struct MyWriter {
  void write(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

In some existing code, the people did not use templates, but interfaces+type-erasure

```
class IWriter {
public:
  virtual ~IWriter() {}

public:
  virtual void write(std::vector<char> const& data) = 0;
};
```

Someone else wanted to be usable with both approaches and writes

```
class MyOwnClass: private MyWriter, public IWriter {
  // other stuff
};
```

MyOwnClass is implemented-in-terms-of MyWriter. Why doesn't MyOwnClass' inherited member functions implement the interface of IWriter automatically? Instead the user has to write forwarding functions that do nothing but call the base class versions, as in

```
class MyOwnClass: private MyWriter, public IWriter {
public:
  void write(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    MyWriter::write(data);
  }
};
```

I know that in Java when you have a class that implements an interface and derives from a class that happens to have suitable methods, that base class automatically implements the interface for the derived class.

Why doesn't C++ do that? It seems like a natural thing to have.

Comment: Java doesn't provide multiple inheritance. How would you expect the compiler to know which `write` are you trying to call from your code?

Comment: Because deriving from  a `struct` doesn't show the same intent as deriving from an `interface`?

Comment: @fontanini I'm not doing multiple inheritance. I derive from a class and implement an interface.

Comment: Why are you using `struct`s instead of `class`es? in fact the `public:` keyword in `IWriter` is useless because you are using `struct`s.

Comment: @BoPersson can you please elaborate? I wanted to derive from a struct to inherit its functionality (MyWriter), and wanted to derive from an interface (IWriter) to be usable in components that employ the interface.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER that's my coding style. I separate the utterly necessary (virtual destructor) from the actual interface. Most of my classes have multiple "private:" in a row (slots, member functions, data members).

Comment: Without `virtual` functions, pure specifications, etc, this makes no sense at all.  Stop trying to cut and paste Java code into C++ and think it's going to work.  litb I expect to know better than this.

Comment: @Johannes - If you derive from a Java `interface` it is pretty obvious that you intend to implement the methods of that interface. Deriving from a C++ `struct` doesn't send an equally strong signal.

Comment: @SigTerm Yes, I'd seen that... JohannesSchaub-litb that's not an interface(at least not in C++).

Comment: @BenVoigt i'm sorry I forgot the "virtual" and pure specifier in the interface definition. Fixed. This is not copy/pasted Java code. I'm not a Java coder.

Comment: OK guys, clarified the question.

Comment: @litb: I already explained why the *base* class implementation can't "implement" the "interface" (which is a peer abstract base class).  A function in the derived class is needed.  Are you asking the compiler to generate that function automatically?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Perhaps some other time. I'm sorry, but at the moment I do not have impression that you actually need help (perhaps I'm mistaken) because of your reputation and "sometimes I'm trolling" statement in profile. And right now I do not find this discussion particularly interesting. I suggest to check C++ FAQ. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Ben a function in the derived class is already provided by the function of the base class. Why does the derived class directly need a function?

Comment: @litb: Because the type of `this`, in `IWriter* p = new MyBigObject(); p->write(v);` is wrong for the base class implementation!

Comment: I don't understand this.

Comment: I really hope you're trolling.

Comment: @Johannes: `MyWriter::write` is non-static, which means it has access to instance members of `MyWriter`.  How does it find them?

Comment: @Ben name lookup has worked for years. I don't know what you are hinting at.

Comment: @fontanini why the hell do you hope that? It’s actually an excellent question with a decidedly nontrivial answer. Five downvotes for a question that most people couldn’t even *think* of is ridiculous.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm referring to his comments, not his question.

Comment: @fontanini He’s asking for clarification. I’m still not sure what you’re objecting to. Consider that Johannes has more or less inhaled the C++ standard and is one of the people with the most comprehensive C++ knowledge on this board, or indeed the internet. When *he* has a question, it’s a good one, and not easily brushed aside.

Comment: @Konrad: The question was considerably worse when it accrued those downvotes.

Comment: I agree with Ben. The question made sense after some edit(s).

Comment: @fontanini: More sense anyway.  I still can't tell whether he's proposing a mechanism that would work without a forwarder, or just wants the compiler to generate the forwarder for him automatically.

Comment: @Ben I’ve looked at the edit history. I don’t agree. Yes, the edit helped clarify, but the original question was in no way worth the downvotes.

Comment: What OP wants is for the compiler to realize that `MyWriter::write` is the implementation of the `IWriter::write` pure virtual method. So rather than automatically generating the forwarded, I believe he wants the `MyWriter::write` method to be the address stored in the `write` entry of `MyOwnClass`'s vtable.

Comment: @Konrad: In the original question, there was no implementation of virtual functions, just a name collision between base class members.  The question has totally changed since then.

Comment: @Ben Ah, I’d overlooked that.

Comment: @Ben yes I'm sorry. I forgot to mark the function virtual and "= 0". Probably should have double looked at it before posting it :(

Comment: @litb: Don't sweat it.  You got some downvotes and comments telling you that, you fixed it, most of the downvotes went away.  That's why we have the voting system.

Answer (score 15):

This is multiple inheritance, and there are two inherited functions with the same signature, **both of which have implementation**.  That's where C++ is different from Java.

Calling `write` on an expression whose static type is `MyBigClass` would therefore be ambiguous as to which of the inherited functions was desired.

<strike>If `write` is only called through base class pointers, then defining `write` in the derived class is NOT necessary, contrary to the claim in the question.</strike>  Now that the question changed to include a pure specifier, implementing that function in the derived class is necessary to make the class concrete and instantiable.

`MyWriter::write` cannot be used for the virtual call mechanism of `MyBigClass`, because the virtual call mechanism requires a function that accepts an implicit `IWriter* const this`, and `MyWriter::write` accepts an implicit `MyWriter* const this`.  A new function is required, which must take into account the address difference between the `IWriter` subobject and the `MyWriter` subobject.

It would be theoretically possible for the compiler to create this new function automatically, but it would be fragile, since a change in a base class could suddenly cause a new function to be chosen for forwarding.  It's less fragile in Java, where only single inheritance is possible (there's only one choice for what function to forward to), but in C++, which supports full multiple inheritance, the choice is ambiguous, and we haven't even started on diamond inheritance or virtual inheritance yet.

Actually, this problem (difference between subobject addresses) is solved for virtual inheritance.  But it requires additional overhead that's not necessary most of the time, and a C++ guiding principle is "you don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: But IWriter::write is a pure virtual function. The compiler can note that and make MyWriter prevent MyBigClass from being abstract.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Of course not.  `MyWriter::write` isn't virtual and has no connection to `IWriter`, and doesn't have the right adjustment thunk for the `this` pointer.  I guess you're asking the compiler to write the forwarding code automatically?  Have you tried `using MyWriter::write;`?

Comment: why does it matter whether or not it is virtual? What prevents putting a rule into the C++ Standard making the case well-formed?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Huh? Is your question "A new implementation in the derived class is clearly needed.  Can't the compiler generate it for me?" or something else?

Comment: base class functions are inherited to derived classes. So the interface is already implemented. But it won't compile because the rules require that we have to write forwarding definitions!

Comment: @Johannes: No, the "interface" is not "implemented".  The base class does not provide any function matching `void write(IMyWriter* const this, std::vector<char> const&)` (using C++ style syntax to show the type of the implicit `this` parameter which is used when calling a virtual function).

Comment: I'm not asking *whether* the interface is implemented. I'm asking *why* the interface is not implemented. I don't understand the "IMyWriter* const this" notion even after you explained this. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "MyWriter::write cannot be placed into the virtual table of MyBigClass, because the virtual table requires a function that accepts an implicit IWriter* const this, and MyWriter::write accepts an implicit MyWriter* const this. ". I don't understand all that. But also, that's a very technical argument for a basic *language design* question. The design of vtables need to follow the design of the language, not the other way around.

Comment: @Johannes: C and C++ work on the opposite principle: The language is designed to provide zero-overhead access to the machine architecture.  So technical implementation details show through frequently.

Comment: About the 'zero-overhead' argument, the language could follow the same rules as it has right now, except that an explicit using declaration could be used to bring a particular base's member function into the derived class (thus bypassing the need for the forwarder boilerplate): `using MyWriter::write;`. This would give fine-grained control, while still not paying for what's not used -- so the OP's question still stands.

Comment: @Luc: Changed to "virtual call mechanism".  Is that better?  The argument is based around the type of `this`, and `this` is a requirement of the language.  And I've repeatedly asked litb if what he's asking is that the compiler generate the forwarder for him, and gotten only argumentative comments in return.

Comment: @Ben i'm not asking the compiler to generate something for me. I'm asking why the current status is what it is. If the compiler must generate MyOwnClass to solve the problem for me, then it must. If there are other solutions, then it could take other solutions. I just want the class not be virtual and a call to IWriter::write end up with behavior equivalent to MyWriter::write. The precise type of &MyOwnClass::write is a different problem - it probably should still be the one of MyWriter::write (so that if the compiler generates a hidden function if needed, that function is *really* hidden).

Comment: But I guess that would be inconsistent because C++ doesn't really have "interfaces", so the function in IWorker is not really "special" apart from being pure. I guess &MyOwnClass::write could remain being ambiguous, but still doing a virtual call of IWriter::write could call MyWriter::write. But those are all details of consequences of allowing what I wonder about, I think.

Comment: @litb: Remember that member function pointers can be used polymorphically.  So `&MyBigClass::write` could just as well refer to `write` from the `IWriter` subobject.  That's a pretty good argument for the forwarder function not to be hidden.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't C++ do that? It seems like a natural thing to have.

Actually, no, it is extremely unnatural thing to have.

Please note that my reasoning is based on my own understanding of "common sense" and can be fundamentally flawed as a result.

You see, you have two different methods, first one in MyWriter, which is non virtual and second one in IWriter which is virtual. They are completely different despite "looking" similar.

I suggest to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660207/as-a-rule-of-thumb-make-all-your-methods-virtual-in-c-sound-advice). The good thing about non-virtual methods is that no matter what you do, as long as they don't call virtual methods, their behavior will never change. I.e. somebody deriving from your class with non-virtual methods will not break existing method by masking them. Virtual methods are designed to be overriden. The price of that is that it is possible to break underlying logic by improperly overriding virtual method. And this is a root of your problem.

Let's say what you propose is allowed. (automatic conversion to virtual with multiple inheritance) There two possible solutions:

**Solution #1**
MyWriter becomes virtual. Consequences: All existing C++ code in the world becomes easy to break via typo or name clash. MyWriter method was not supposed to be overriden initially, so suddenly turning it into virtual will (murphy's law) break underlying logic of MyWriter class when somebody derives from MyOwnClass. Which means that suddenly making MyWriter::write virtual is a bad idea.

**Soluion #2**
MyWriter remains static BUUUT it is included temporarily as a virtual method into IWriter, until overriden. At first glance there's nothing to worry about, but let's think about it. IWriter implements some kind of concept you had in mind, and it is supposed to do something. MyWriter implements another concept. To assign MyWriter::write as IWriter::write method you need two guarantees:

1. Compiler must ensure that MyWriter::write does what IWriter::write() is supposed to do.
2. Compiler must ensure that calling MyWriter::write from IWriter will not break existing functionality in MyWriter code programmer expects to use elsewhere.

So, the thing is that compiler cannot guarantee that. Functions have similar name and argument list, but by Murphy's law that means that they're prbably doing completely different thing. (sinf and cosf have same argument list, for example), and it is unlikely that compiler will be able to predict the future and make sure that at no point in development will MyWriter be changed in such way that it will become incompatible with IWriter. So, since machine can't make reasonable decision (no AI for that) by itself, it has to ask YOU, programmer - "What is it you wish to do?". And you say "redirect virtual method into MyWriter::write(). It totally won't break anything. I think.".

And that's why you must specify which method you want to use manually....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a few questions. "Compiler must ensure that MyWriter::write does what IWriter::write() is supposed to do.". Why is it the compiler and not the programmer that has to ensure that? The programmer is the one who derived MyOwnClass from the interface and MyWriter, so he better checks that MyWriter satisfies IWriter.

Comment: I see the same thing with this: `struct A { void nonVirtualNastiness() {} virtual void bark() { } };` then the author of `A` decides to derive from an interface `struct A : public IDoggy { virtual void bark() { } };`. Now `IDoggy::bark` too automatically is overridden by `A::bark` and the compiler trusts the programmer that he checked their compatibility. And `nonVirtualNastiness` may suddenly become virtual automatically by the inheritance because the baseclass has it virtual.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: "Why is it the compiler and not the programmer that has to ensure that?" IF compiler were to automatically assign method from MyClass as virtual implmentation of IWriter, then it would need to ensure that. If compiler cannot ensure, then compiler would need to make an assumption about internal program logic, and by Murphy's law any automatic assumption will be incorrect. So it makes sense to ask programmer for info. In my experience, good automatic system aimed at experienced users should never make any assumption about anything - it should ask for user decision. (cont)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: (cont) with current implementation programmer is the one ensuring everything works as expected, and programmer has to decide. It is kinda similar to linux distros - "user-friendly" distribution (like ubuntu) will assume that user doesn't always know what he is doing and might select some action/configuration choice silently, which can annoy user a LOT. "power-user" distribution will never get in your way, will never decide anything for you and will always do exactly what you *asked* it to do. (cont)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: ..(cont) such behavior (do exactly as you said) gives user full control, but at the cost of accidentally performing harmful command. As far as I can tell C++ follows "power-user" mode and I like it this way - programmer should be the one making decisions. Of course, this is a matter of personal preference. To be fair, the whole thing is matter of taste and is a matter of subjective opinion. I'm comfortable with language working as it is and don't see much of benefit from implementing scheme you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Doing it *automatically* would be unintuitive and surprising. C++ does not assume that multiple base classes are related to each other, and protects the user against name collisions between their members by defining nested name specifiers for nonstatic members. Adding implicit declarations to `MyOwnClass` where signatures from `IWriter` and `MyWriter` collide would be antithetical to protecting names.

However, C++11 extensions do bring us closer. Consider this:

```
class MyOwnClass: private MyWriter, public IWriter {
public:
  void write(std::vector<char> const& data) final = MyWriter::write;
};
```

This mechanism would be safe because it expresses that `MyWriter` doesn't expect any further overrides, and convenient because it names the function signature that will be "joined" but nothing more. Also, `final` would be ill-formed if the function weren't implicitly `virtual`, so it checks that the signature matches the virtual interface.

On one hand, most interfaces don't just happen to match up this way. Defining this feature to work only with identical signatures would be safe but rarely useful. Defining it as a shortcut to a delegating function body would be useful but fragile. So it might not really be a good feature

On the other hand, this is a good design pattern to provide functionality which isn't virtual when you don't need it to be. So given this idiom, we might use it to write good code, even if it doesn't match up well with current practices.

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't C++ do that?

I'm not sure what you're asking here. *Could* C++ be rewritten to allow this? Yes, but to what end?

Because `MyWriter` and `IWriter` are completely different classes, it is illegal in C++ to call a member of `MyWriter` through an instance of `IWriter`. The member pointers have completely different types. And just as a `MyWriter*` is not convertible to a `IWriter*`, neither is a `void (MyWriter::*)(const std::vector<char>&)` convertible to a `void (IWriter::*)(const std::vector<char>&)`.

The rules of C++ don't change just because there *could* be a third class that combines the two. Neither class is a direct parent/child relative of one another. Therefore, they are treated as entirely distinct classes.

Remember: member functions always take an additional parameter: a `this` pointer to the object that they point to. You cannot call `void (MyWriter::*)(const std::vector<char>&)` on an `IWriter*`. The third class can have a method that casts itself into the proper base class, but it must actually *have this method*. So either you or the C++ compiler must create it. The rules of C++ require this.

Consider what would have to happen to make this work without a derived-class method.

A function gets an `IWriter*`. The user calls the `write` member of it, using nothing more than the `IWriter*` pointer. So... exactly how can the compiler generate the code to call `MyWriter::writer`? Remember: `MyWriter::writer` **needs** a `MyWriter` instance. And there is no relationship between `IWriter` and `MyWriter`.

So how exactly could the compiler do the type coercion locally? The compiler would have to check the virtual function to see if the actual function to be called takes `IWriter` or some other type. If it takes another type, it would have to convert the pointer to its true type, then do another conversion to the type needed by the virtual function. After doing all of that, it would then be able to make the call.

All of this overhead would affect *every* virtual call. All of them would have to at least check to see if the actual function to be call. Every call will also have to generate the code to do the type conversions, just in case.

Every virtual function call would have a "get type" and conditional branch in it. Even if it is *never* possible to trigger that branch. So you would be paying for something regardless of whether you use it or not. That's not the C++ way.

Even worse, a straight v-table implementation of virtual calls is no longer possible. The fastest method of doing virtual dispatch would not be a conforming implementation. The C++ committee is ***not*** going to make any change that would make such implementations impossible.

Again, to what end? Just so that you don't have to write a simple forwarding function?

Comment: I'm not literally asking for the ability to directly call `MyWriter::write` by calling `IWriter::write`. I just don't want to put a function definition into `MyOwnClass` that just forwards to `MyWriter::write`. Can the compiler not do that for me? All I wonder about is: The resulting object could be set up such that a call to `IWriter::write` *ends up* calling `MyWriter::write`. There can be trampolines and whatnot in between them (whatever needed to make it work) that eventually do the final call to `MyWriter::write`.

Comment: In this case, the language too allows the cross case of `A` to `B` even though neither class " is a direct parent/child relative of one another". But objects of both classes appear as subobjects of a single complete object: `struct A { virtual ~A() {}}; struct B { virtual ~B() {} void f() {}}; struct C : A, B {}; int main() { A *a = new C; dynamic_cast<B*>(a)->f(); }`. In my case too, both classes appear as base classes of a single derived class.

Comment: @Johannes: "Can the compiler not do that for me?" Yes, it could. But it wouldn't do it implicitly, so you'd still need *some* syntax there to tell the compiler to do it. And since that syntax needs a function signature, as well as the name (and likely the signature) of the function to call... it would really just be a small bit of syntactic sugar for writing the forwarding function yourself. Feel free to propose this to the C++1y standardization committee. I wouldn't expect it to gain much traction though, considering how much of a corner case it is.

Comment: @litb: Does the language allow cross-cast in this case?  I thought both types were required to be polymorphic, and `MyWriter` isn't.  Besides, `dynamic_cast` is expensive.

Answer (score -2):

Just make MyWriter derive from IWriter, eliminate the IWriter derivation in MyOwnClass, and move on with life. This should resolve the problem and should not interfere with the template code.