# why it is not possible to implement inherited pure virtual method with 'using' directive?

Tags: c++, interface, using-directives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C++ not let baseclasses implement a derived class' inherited interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464308/why-does-c-not-let-baseclasses-implement-a-derived-class-inherited-interface)

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void yell(void) = 0;
};

class Implementation
{
public:
    void yell(void)
    {
        std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Test: private Implementation, public Interface
{
public:
    using Implementation::yell;
};

int main (void)
{
    Test t;
    t.yell();
}
```

I want the `Test` class to be implemented in terms of `Implementation`, and I want to avoid the need to write the

```
void Test::yell(void) { Implementation::yell(); }
```

method. Why it is not possible to do it this way? Is there any other way in C++03?

Comment: @mofntanini: yeah, but since that question has lots of *incorrect* answers (just tacitly assuming the OP's assertions are correct) it would be much better to vote that other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using` only brings a name into a scope.

It doesn't implement anything.

If you want Java-like get-implementation-by-inheritance, then you have to explicitly add the overhead associated with that, namely `virtual` inheritance, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void yell() = 0;
};

class Implementation
    : public virtual Interface
{
public:
    void yell()
    {
        std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Test: private Implementation, public virtual Interface
{
public:
    using Implementation::yell;
};

int main ()
{
    Test t;
    t.yell();
}
```

---

**EDIT**: a bit sneaky this feature, I had to edit to make the code compile with g++. Which didn't automatically recognize that the implementation `yell` and the interface `yell` were one and the same. I'm not completely sure what the standard says about that!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Considering wtfpm only, do you think it is better to do it with virtual inheritance, or I should just make the hierarchy linear with public inheritance? My real hierarchy is the same, only the classes are more complex

Comment: @Dadam: the general rule is first make it correct, and only then make it fast (if necessary). so the general guideline has always been to inherit virtually from interface classes. that helps with exceptions too.

Comment: In this case, speed is really not a problem, I just want to make it readable (you know [wtfpm](http://davidlongstreet.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/new-software-metric-wtfs-per-minute/), don't you?).

Comment: he he, i did, but not that acronym

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - The `using` is needed because of the private inheritance from `Implementation`, public inheritance from `Interface`. The public inheritance from `Interface` mandates that you have to provide a `yell()` whose visibility is `public` to qualify as a non-abstract class. You are inheriting `yell()` from `Implementation`, but without the `using` it's visibility is `private`.

Comment: @DavidHammen: thank you for your comment. i am sure it was well meant. but no, accessibility has nothing to do with abstractness, and is not part of a function's signature.

Comment: So let me repeat the OP's question: why isn't it possible to do what the OP wants with `using`? why isn't `using` extended to also cover this functionality? You didn't actually answer the question. I won't downvote you because I disagree with this kind of ridiculous, offensive and unnecessary downvoting, but it's a bit rich to downvote my answer simply because you disagree with half of of it, and failed to read the other half, *when your own answer fails to answer the question actually posed by the OP*

Comment: @jalf: re "why", to flesh it out a bit more than above, the `using` feature is *unrelated* to method implementation. you're right that the word "using" is a very general one in common English, so that it could be re-used in some new feature. but that new feature would be a different, new feature, only superficially similar to current `using`, namely in the use of the same English word. there is no point in common between scope and method implementation. Historically `using` replaced the pre-standard technique of *re-declaring* methods. You can then see that they're not implementations.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf see, that wasn't so hard, was it? If you'd put that in your answer in the first place, then you could legitimately criticise my answer for being incomplete. (I still disagree with downvoting a correct, but incomplete question for subjective reasons, especially when a simple comment would have done)

Comment: @jalf: I do not want to extended anything. Is my english _that_ bad? I am just asking why my class does not work. And how I can make it work. Both questions are answered in this answer (@Cheersandhth.-Alf: please do not put anything about extending the `using` keyword in it). On the other side, _the first version_ of your answer was just about my question being stupid.