# Delegate part of an interface to a subclass in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a relatively complex interface in my code, and would like to delegate part of the implementation to another class, without writing lots of forwarding functions in the implementation. See this simplified example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Interface {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

struct Delegate {
    virtual void foo()
    { printf("foo\n"); }
};


struct Impl : public Interface, private Delegate {
    // delegate foo to Delegate
    using Delegate::foo;

    void bar()
    { printf("bar\n"); }
};

int main() {
    Interface* i = new Impl();
    i->foo();
    i->bar();
    delete i;
    return 0;
}
```

Now G++ complains that *foo* is not implemented in Impl. However, there is a perfectly fine function *foo* in Impl, it's just taken from another parent class. Why won't the compiler fill in the vtable appropriately?

(Note: I know that Delegate could derive from Interface in this particular example. I'd like to understand if it would be possible to delegate the functionality without having to derive the delegate from the interface.)

Comment: I remember there was a long discussion in this thread, about the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464308/why-does-c-not-let-baseclasses-implement-a-derived-class-inherited-interface. Unfortunately, I believe there's no way to do this.

Comment: Is it possible in Java or C# ?

Comment: @MM. yes, at least in Java, it can be done.