# Why should I mark all methods virtual in C++? Is there a trade-off?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I know why and how virtual methods work, and most of the time people tell me I should always mark a method virtual, but, I don't understand why if I'm not going to override it. And I also know there's a tiny memory issue.

Please explain me why I should mark all methods virtual and what's the trade-off.

Code example:

```
class Point
{
   int x, y;
   public:
      virtual void setX(int i);
      virtual void setY(int i);
};
```

(That question is not equal to [Should I mark all methods virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451325/should-i-mark-all-methods-virtual) because I want to know the trade-off and because the programming language in the case is C++, not C#)

OBS: I'm sorry if there's any grammar error, English is not my native language.

Comment: How told you this? `virtual` function calls usually involve a vtable lookup and cannot be inlined. If you don't need them, don't use them.

Comment: Check the Wrox Professional C++ book, they say I should always mark a method virtual.

Comment: Not everything written in a book is good advice. Not even if the title contains the word "Professional".

Comment: All the reasons given in the accepted answer to that other question are language agnostic, i.e. they apply to C++ just as much as to C#.

Comment: *"most of the time people tell me I should always mark a method virtual"* - You should see different people :) Seriously, though, this advice is complete nonsense. No professional software engineer I've ever known, be it personally or through a book or on the Internet, would tell you that (and I have an MSc in software engineering and work full-time as a software engineer). Never heard of "Wrox Professional C++", but if it contains such advice, you should probably throw it away and replace it with a good book.

Comment: @delnan: True, although the details differ. For example, in Java a method is meant to be overridden by default, and you have to prevent that using `final`.

Comment: @celtschk unless of course it's called "professional ways make slow down code that you can increase the speed of later so you get a raise"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["As a rule of thumb, make all your methods virtual" in C++ - sound advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660207/as-a-rule-of-thumb-make-all-your-methods-virtual-in-c-sound-advice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should not "mark all methods as virtual".

If you want the method to be virtual, then mark it as such. If not, leave the keyword out.

There is an overhead for virtual methods compared to regular ones. If you want to read more about this, check out the Wikipedia side about [VTables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 3):

The real reason to make member functions non-virtual is to enforce class invariants.

Advice to make all member functions virtual generally means that either:

1. The people giving the advice don't understand the class, or
2. the people giving the advice don't understand OO design.

Yes, there are a few cases (e.g., some abstract base classes, where the only class invariant is the existence of specific functions) in which all the functions should be virtual. Those are the exception though. In most classes, virtual functions should be restricted to those that you really intend to allow derived classes to provide new/different behavior.

As for the discussion of things like vtables and the overhead of virtual function calls, I'd say they're correct as far as they go, *but* they miss the really big point. Whether a particular function should or shouldn't be virtual is primarily a question of class design and only secondarily a question of function call overhead. The two don't do the same thing, so trying to compare overhead rarely makes sense.

Comment: +1 because it highlights the central point. Performance penalties are only a side effect of bad class design.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the case, ie, if you dont need a virtual function then dont use it. Also as per **Bjarne Stroustrup** **[Pay per use](http://www.stroustrup.com/#virtual)**

> In C++: --
>
> 1. Virtual functions have a slight performance penalty.  Normally it is too small to make any difference but in a tight loop it might be
>      significant.
> 2. A virtual function increases the size of each object by one pointer.  Again this is typically insignificant, but if you create
>      millions of small objects it could be a factor.
> 3. Classes with virtual functions are generally meant to be inherited from.  The derived classes may replace some, all or none of the
>      virtual functions.  This can create additional complexity and
>      complexity is the programmers mortal enemy.  For example, a derived
>      class may poorly implement a virtual function.  This may break a part
>      of the base class that relies on the virtual function.

Answer (score 2):

One of C++'s basic principles is that you don't pay for what you don't need.  `virtual` functions *cost* more than normal member functions in both time and space.  Therefore you shouldn't *always* use them irregardless of whether or not you'll actually ever need them or not.

Comment: The principle you mention is one of *language design* and it's more accurately stated as "don't pay for what you don't *use*". A programmer may still decide to always use some feature; this answer doesn't give a strong reason to not use virtual functions IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Making methods virtual has slight costs (more code, more complexity, larger binaries, slower method calls), and if the class is not inherited from it brings no benefit. Classes need to be designed for inheritance, otherwise inheriting from them is just begging to shoot yourself in the foot. So no, you should not always make every method virtual. The people who tell you this are probably just too inheritance-happy.

Comment: Class most certainly **don't** need to designed for inheritance. Compile time polymorphism is one of many examples that don't. Most of the classes in the standard library is another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that all functions should be marked as virtual.

Indeed, there's a pattern for enforcing pre/postconditions which explicitly requires that public members are *not* virtual. It works as follows:

```
class Whatever
{
public:
  int frobnicate(int);
protected:
  virtual int do_frobnicate(int);
};

int Whatever::frobnicate(int x)
{
  check_preconditions(x);
  int result = do_frobnicate(x);
  check_postconditions(x, result);
  return result;
}
```

Since derived classes cannot override the public function, they cannot remove the pre/postcondition checks. They can, however, override the protected `do_frobnicate` which does the actual work.

Comment: You should make the virtual function `private`, not `protected`, although I know of one (but only one) C++ guru who thinks otherwise. btw, Herb Sutter once called this pattern "Non-Virtual Interface Idiom": http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Answer (score -1):

(Edit - I got to this question by way of a duplicate C# question, but the answer is still useful, I think!  Edited to reflect that:)

Actually, C# has a good "official" reason:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/versioning-with-the-override-and-new-keywords

The first sentence there is:

> The C# language is designed so that versioning between base and derived classes in different libraries can evolve and maintain backward compatibility.

So if you're writing a class and it's possible end-users will make derived classes, and it's possible different versions will get out of sync...all of a sudden it starts to be important.  If you have carefully protected core aspects of your code, then if you update things, people can still use the old derived class (hopefully).

On the other hand, if you are okay with no one being able to used derived classes until their authors have updated to your newest version, everything can be virtual.  I have seen this scenario in several "early access" games that allow modding - when the game version increases, all of a sudden a lot of mods are broken because they relied on things working one way...and they changed.  (Okay, not all changes are related to this, but some are.)

It really depends on your usage scenario.  If people can keep using your old version, maybe they don't care if you've updated it and are happy to keep using it with their derived classes.  In a large business scenario, making everything virtual may very well be a recipe for breaking many things at once when someone updates something.

Does this apply to C++ as well?  I don't see why not - C++ is also used for massive projects and would also face the dangers of multiple simultaneous versions.

Comment: **the programming language in the case is C++, not C#**

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are quite right - I got here from a duplicate from someone asking about C#.  The answers still hold, I think, altho my frustration with C# is not appropriate.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that.  Thank you for letting me know.